# extjs redirectTo method called twice from another controller

Tags: extjs, extjs5

The problem is in redirectTo calling onLoad method twice. From my main viewport extra views are loading dynamically.

Having main viewport

```
Ext.define('MyApp.main.view.MainView', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    id: 'mainViewPort',
    requires: [
        'MyApp.main.controller.MainViewController',
    ],
    xtype: 'app-main',
    controller: 'main',
    viewModel: {
        type: 'main'
    },
    layout: {
        type: 'border'
    },
    items: [{
        region: 'center'
    }]
});
```

viewport controller

```
Ext.define('MyApp.main.controller.MainViewController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.main',
    onClickQueryResponses: function() {
        var panelToAddName = Ext.create('MyApp.requests.view.QueryResponsesGridView', {});
        var mainViewPort = Ext.getCmp('mainViewPort');
        var centerRegion = mainViewPort.down('[region=center]');
        centerRegion.removeAll();
        centerRegion.add(panelToAddName);
    }
});
```

view 'MyApp.requests.view.QueryResponsesGridView'

```
Ext.define('MyApp.requests.view.QueryResponsesGridView', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    requires: [
        'MyApp.requests.controller.QueryResponsesGridViewController'
    ],
    controller: 'queryResponsesGrid',
    dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            items:[{
                xtype: 'button',
                margin: '0 30 0 4',
                handler: 'onClickQuerySearch'
            }]
        }]
    });
});
```

controller of view 'MyApp.requests.view.QueryResponsesGridView'

```
Ext.define('MyApp.requests.controller.QueryResponsesGridViewController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.queryResponsesGrid',
    routes : {
        'responses': {
            action  : 'onLoad'
        }
    },
    onLoad: function() {
        this.redirectTo('responses');
        alert('!');
    },
    onClickQuerySearch: function() {
        this.onLoad();
    },
});
```

When I click button with handler onClickQuerySearch alert('!') is running twice, do anyone know why?

here is the fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/oqb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need to call `redirectTo` in the `onLoad` method.  You are basically creating a self-referencing loop.  `redirectTo` is then calling `onLoad` again.

I think possibly you want the `redirectTo` in the `onClickQuerySearch` instead of calling `onLoad` directly:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.QueryResponsesGridViewController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.queryResponsesGrid',
    routes : {
        'responses': {
            action  : 'onLoad'
        }
    },
    onLoad: function() {
        alert('!');
    },
    onClickQuerySearch: function() {
        this.redirectTo('responses');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this is it. I just thought redirectTo should only update the hash and not create a self-referencing loop. Anyway in redirectTo method force the update set to false, that means it should not execute the routes if the current token and the token passed are the same. I already wrote to sencha about this issue.